New to stored procedures; need help in creating procedure
I am new to procedures and trying to create a procedure to delete entries from tables.
Tables names will be in query 1. My request_id will be in another query which entries I need to delete.
How do I start a procedure to prepare delete statements now
query_1 o/p Query_2 o/p
Table_1        15
Table_2        23
Table_3        33

My delete statement should be
delete Table_1 
where request_id in (15, 23, 33);

delete Table_2 
where request_id in (15, 23, 33);

delete Table_3 
where request_id in (15, 23, 33);

I tried assigning the output from query_1 to a variable and the output from query_2 to another variable.
But I'm not sure how to prepare delete statement here.

It depends of the RDBMS that you want to use...

In what form do you want your output? Why don't you just select the rows prior to deleting them? Or use variables to record their existence before reporting them all at the end. (Note that you might need some additional handling for transactions that get rolled back.)
